# Rails: Non id foreign key lookup ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-key-relationship, has-many, belongs-to

I want `ActiveRecord` to lookup by a non-id column from a table.
Hope this is clear when I give you my code sample.

```
class CoachClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coach
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :coach_classes, :foreign_key => 'user_name'
end
```

When I do a 
`coach_obj.coach_classes`, this rightly triggers

```
SELECT * FROM `coach_classes` WHERE (`coach_classes`.user_name = 2)
```

(2 being the that coach's `id` here which is my problem.)

I want it to trigger

```
SELECT * FROM `coach_classes` WHERE (`coach_classes`.user_name = 'David')
```

('David' being the that coach's `user_name`)

`user_name` is unique and present in both tables.

I do not want to have a `coach_id` in my `coach_classes` table for some reason.

Comment: unsolicited advice: you may want to consider adding a coach_id to the table, it will make it easier if this relationship becomes nested and more conventional.

Comment: Thanks Jed. But I do not want coach_id there for some reason.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think you need to specify the primary key options on the associations as well:

```
class CoachClass < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :coach, :foreign_key => 'user_name', :primary_key => 'user_name'
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :coach_classes, :foreign_key => 'user_name', :primary_key => 'user_name'
end
```

This specifies the method that returns the primary key of the associated object (defaulting to `id`).

Comment: John, are you sure the other side of the association has an effect here? One could simply have `has_many`, without a `belongs_to` on the other side.

Comment: I have scoured the internet for this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

There is a option called `primary_key` which is per default set to `:id`. You want to use:

```
has_many :coach_classes, :foreign_key => :user_name, :primary_key => :user_name
```

Also use these options on the `belongs_to` association.

Read more in the [documentation](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316).

Answer (score -6):

You need to use `finder_sql`:

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :coach_classes, :finder_sql => 'SELECT * FROM `coach_classes` WHERE (`coach_classes`.user_name = "#{user_name}")'
end
```

Comment: Note - they took this away in later versions.  Really a lifesaver when their 'magic' doesn't have the functionality you need.

Comment: Definitely do not do this... ever.