# How to add reference to a non primary key column of a table in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, foreign-keys

I am using Rails 5.0.1 for web development and deploying my app on Heroku. I am using postgreSQL as my database for Heroku and sqlite3 for my local development database.

I need to link to an `account_number` column of an Accounts table to two columns in a Transactions table. The `account_number` column is not the primary key of Accounts table.

And, the Transactions table has a column `from_account`, which I want to link to the `account_number` column in `Accounts` table and 
another column - `to_account` that I want to link to the same `account_number` column of `Accounts` table.

The `account_number` is not the primary key of accounts table **but it is unique**.

I am trying to do something like this in my migration file:

```
create_table :transactions do |t|
  t.string :from_account, foreign_key: true
  t.string :to_account, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
end

add_foreign_key :transactions, column: :from_account, :accounts, column: :account_number
add_foreign_key :transactions, column: :to_account, :accounts, column: :account_number
```

and my model file looks like this:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :from_account, :foreign_key => 'from_account', :class_name => 'Account'
  belongs_to :to_account, :foreign_key => 'to_account', :class_name => 'Account'
end
```

But this gives error on both my local sqlite3 database and also on the Heroku's PostgreSQL database.

How do I model something like this in Rails5.
So far all the tutorials I found online only tell how to link to the primary key of the referenced table.

**EDIT**: Maybe it is unclear from my question above, but the account_number field is already unique in the Accounts table in my database. This is the schema of my Accounts table:

```
create_table :accounts do |t|
  t.string :account_number, :unique => true
  # Other fields
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Yes, the account_number is unique. Also could you please elaborate a bit about the "refer to this via a Foreign Key" part? How exactly do I do that, other than the way I have already done as mentioned in the question?

Comment: I don't know RoR (don't need to, don't want to) In DDL it is simple the *target* for the FK should be at least UNIQUE (possibly a Primary Key), like I commented earlier. So , in the definition for "Transaction" : `... from_account INTEGER REFERENCES "Account" (Account_number) ...` Similar for to_account, of course. BTW: `Transaction` is a bad name for a table, it is also a keyword in SQL.

Comment: Also, now I see `t.string :from_account,` which probably means that it is a varchar or text column. Which is a bad choice, because character columns are *heavier* than plain ints. I'd prefer a FK to a surrogate column (probably your PK) instead. (but keep the UNIQUE constraint on the text column, of course)

Comment: from_account INTEGER REFERENCES "Account" (Account_number)  doesn't work on RoR / PostgreSQL. and thanks for suggesting that Transaction is a keyword I guess I should change that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I found the solution to my problem in another answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try primary_key:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :from_account, :foreign_key => 'from_account', :class_name  => 'Account', :primary_key => 'account_number'
  belongs_to :to_account, :foreign_key => 'to_account', :class_name => 'Account', :primary_key => 'account_number'
end
```

Comment: would using :primary_key => 'account_number' make the account_number column the primary key of account table. Also, is there no way to reference a column which is just a unique column, but not the primary key

Comment: Thanks Archana, this solution worked both on PostgreSQL and sqlite3. and I still have the account_number masked as just unique in Accounts table. I am still not sure whether the changes you suggested made the account_number the primary key now or not.

Comment: @sumit No, the :primary_key doesn't affect any primary keys. It's misnamed; see my answer.

Comment: is it applicable only to rails 5 or would work with rails 4.2

Answer (score 3):

As [Arcana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403114/3404097) says, give the referenced column via `:primary_key`:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :from_account, :foreign_key => 'from_account', :class_name => 'Account',
    :primary_key => 'account_number'
  belongs_to :to_account, :foreign_key => 'to_account', :class_name => 'Account',
    :primary_key => 'account_number'
end
```

The language `:primary_key` in the `belongs_to` is misleading. It should really be `:candidate_key` or `:references` or `:unique` or `primary_key_or_unique`. But it isn't. It doesn't affect what the primary key in the referenced class is.

[Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

> 4 Detailed Association Reference
> 4.1 belongs_to Association Reference
> 4.1.2 Options for `belongs_to`
> 4.1.2.6 `:primary_key`
>
> By convention, Rails assumes that the id column is used to hold the primary key of its tables. The `:primary_key` option allows you to specify a different column.

(In the relational model, a foreign key references a candidate key, which is some unique (not null) column set that doesn't contain a smaller unique (not null) column set, and is some set of columns you could have picked as primary key. But in (Active Record and) SQL a `PRIMARY KEY` actually declares a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` (that might contain a smaller `UNIQUE NOT NULL`) and a `FOREIGN KEY` `REFERENCES` a `UNIQUE NOT NULL`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that it's caused by either not specifying a primary key [during your migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) or [within your model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317644/rails-non-id-foreign-key-lookup-activerecord)